# Decode entities in node titles

Tags: 7, security

I have a few node titles that are being saved with & and displaying that way too.

Is there any way to not encode them while being saved? I tried:

```
$node = node_load(727);
$node->title = html_entity_decode($node->title);
node_save($node);
```

I dump out the node and the title is corrected, but is not saved that way. Should I only try to correct the display using the same function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Filter input, escape output](http://shiflett.org/blog/2005/feb/more-on-filtering-input-and-escaping-output). You can't be sure that everything in your database is safe.